# Is it good practice to lock on a threaded instance of an object being used throughout an application?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Every example I've ever seen of locking uses a private object to lock specific blocks of code, and [Thread Synchronization (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179.aspx) gives the same kind of example, but also says  "Strictly speaking, the object provided is used solely to uniquely identify the resource being shared among multiple threads, so it can be an arbitrary class instance. **In practice, however, this object usually represents the resource for which thread synchronization is necessary.**" (Emphasis mine.) In my example here, and in my code, there is only one instance of "MyClass", which is running on its own thread, and a reference to it is passed around to various other classes.

Is it OK to lock on the MyClass reference and then call Ready(), or should I instead put a private object() within MyClass and lock on that, as shown in the LockedReady() method? Thank you for your answer, in advance.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var uc = new UserClass();
            uc.DoThings();
        }
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        public bool Ready()
        { 
            //determine if the class is ready to perform its function
            //assumes that the instance of MyClass is locked, 
            //as shown in UserClass.DoThings
        }

        private object _readyLock = new object();
        public bool LockedReady()
        {
            lock (_readyLock)
            {
                //determine if the class is ready to perform its function
                //no assumption made that the object is locked, as 
                //shown in AnotherClass.DoAnotherThing()    
            }
        }

    }


    public class UserClass
    {
        private MyClass _myc;

        public UserClass()
        {
            var t = new Thread(SetupMyClass);
            t.Start();
        }

        private void SetupMyClass()
        {
            _myc = new MyClass();
        }

        public void DoThings()
        {
            lock(_myc)
            {
                if (_myc.Ready())
                {
                    //Do things
                }
            }
        }

        public void DoOtherThings()
        {
            var ac = new AnotherClass(_myc);
            ac.DoAnotherThing();
        }
    }

    public class AnotherClass
    {
        private MyClass _myc;

        public AnotherClass(MyClass myClass)
        {
            _myc = myClass;
        }

        public void DoAnotherThing()
        {
            if (_myc.LockedReady())
                {
                    //do another thing
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `lock` doesn't work the way your code suggests you think it does. It simply blocks until the lock can be acquired.

Comment: Right, but once the lock is acquired on the object, can't the locking thread then make use of the locked objects methods and properties, exclusively, until the lock is released?

Comment: Locks are voluntary. It requires cooperation from all threads. One way to guarantee cooperation is by encapsulating the lock management inside obligatory methods. Only then are locks automatic. But locks don't magically lock down the object. If one thread takes a lock, and another thread ignores a lock, then the 2nd thread is free to trample (unless the methods themselves contain the locking code).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functionally, it doesn't matter, one object doesn't perform better than the other, unless there is shared use of that object by other locking concerns.

With C#, it isn't uncommon to lock on the actual domain object, rather than a surrogate object for the lock. It is also common to see a member object used, and a common legacy example is the SyncRoot object on the early System.Collections. Either way works, as long as you use a reference type.

**However**, the argument to be made for using an internal surrogate lock object is one of **encapsulation**. It eliminates the possibility of external interference if a user of your class decides to use your class as a lock. Using an internal lock object protects your locks from external interference, so one could argue that locking is an implementation detail that should be hidden.

The important thing is to ensure it is correct and appropriate. Make sure your locking is done at an appropriate granularity. (For example, using a static lock object probably isn't the best approach for a non-singleton, and probably not even most singletons). In cases where your class has multiple mutually exclusive threaded operations, you don't want to lock on "this" or you have unnecessary contention. That is like having one red light for 2 non-overlapping intersections.